# In Meanjs, adding new lib in bower.json not automatically added to the config file

Tags: javascript, bower, meanjs

I am learning Meanjs. I need to add Fontawesome for my project. So I added an entry in bower.json as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "~3",
    "angular": "~1.2",
    "angular-resource": "~1.2",
    "angular-mocks": "~1.2",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.2",
    "angular-animate": "~1.2",
    "angular-touch": "~1.2",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.2",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.11.0",
    "angular-ui-utils": "~0.1.1",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.10",
    "fontawesome": "~4.1.0"
}
```

and ran 'bower install'. Packages downloaded successfully, but fontawesome is not linked automatically in my page. Should I have to manually link those libs?

Please help.

Comment: In "AngularJS generator(https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular)" project if you add an entry in bower.json for extra libraries, it will automatically link those to index page and eventually you can use those libs in all your pages. There is no manual linking of those libs. My question is: 'Is there any automatic mechanism available in MEAN.js for similar kind of feature'?

Answer (score 4):

The step you are missing is to add the entry in your config/env/***.js file(s). There is a library section where you will see other libraries. The config/env files are what determines the links that are added to the head tag.

I don't know of an automatic way to add these entries.

Comment: Worked for me, i added the following:
```css: [
   'public/modules/**/css/*.css',
   'public/lib/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'
  ]```

Answer (score 2):

For:
    `"meanjs-version": "0.4.2"`

Add the path to the library to:
    `/config/assets/*.js`

Example:
    `/config/assets/default.js`

```
module.exports = {
  client: {
    lib: {
      css: [
        'public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
        'public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css',
        'public/lib/angular-typewrite/dist/angular-typewrite.css'
      ],
      js: [
        'public/lib/angular/angular.js',
        'public/lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
        'public/lib/angular-typewrite/dist/angular-typewrite.js'
      ]
    }
   }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To auto update dependencies I've used wiredep in the past.

```
npm install --save-dev grunt-wiredep
```

In your Gruntfile.js you'll have a block that looks like this:

```
grunt.initConfig({

 //bunch of tasks in here
 clean: {...},
 jshint:{...},
 //add the following lines
  wiredep: {
    src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html', 'you can add', 'other search paths', 'here'],
    block: /(([ \t]*)\/\/\s*bower:*(\S*))(\n|\r|.)*?(\/\/\s*endbower)/gi,  
    replace: {
      js: '{{filePath}}',
     }
    }
  });
```

Once that's added as a task add the task to your task list

```
grunt.registerTask('testOrWhateverYoursIsCalled', [
  //your other tasks here
  'wiredep'
 ]);
```

Then in your .config file or wherever you have your big list of js files add this:

```
 //bower:js
 //this will get swapped out for your list of bower components
 //endbower
```

The path might be weird, but I think you can use cwd to change the path.  Not sure how do do that, just played with getting wiredep to replace things and it worked!!

Just answered my first question on stack, FINALLY!!!

Answer (score -1):

Probably you should add

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

to your index.html

Comment: In a meanjs project, links to the jsfiles are added automatically. The question is what do you have to do to avoid this manual step.